# Динамическое изменение классов посредством javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть слайдер `slick`, 6 изображений, 3 активных (то есть на странице показывается только 3 картинки). Хочу чтобы блок с картинкой, который по центру был с `opacity:1`, а блок от него слева и справа - `opacity:0.5`. Так как есть прокрутка, рендорятся блоки, **css** понятное дело не срабатывает. Но и **js** тоже, нужна постоянная проверка изменений.

Как это можно реализовать?

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="item1"></div>
   <div class="item2"></div>
   <div class="item3"></div>
   <div class="item4"></div>
   <div class="item5"></div>
   <div class="item6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: сделай [mcve] с плагином

Comment: кто знает о чем я, тот понял меня!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У slick слайда есть класс slick-slide, у активного слайда есть класс slick-current. Соответственно css может быть таким:

```
.slick-slide:not(.slick-current) {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: да, это работает, но почему то у меня slick-current стоит в начале списка а не поцентру?

Comment: разобрался, спасибо !!